# android- how can I compile my codes online?

Tags: android

I just want to know is there any way to compile and run my android application codes online, without installing the SDK on the computer ?

Thanks!

Abhinav.

Comment: I think you can't. can you tell us why you don't want to/can't have the sdk on your computer ?

Comment: Actually ,I am using a very outdated computer and dont have muxh memory to install the applications/softwares..So, it would be better if I could compile and run the code online.

Answer (score 4):

Nitobi, the company behind Phonegap, has an [online compiler for Phonegap applications](http://build.phonegap.com/).

It enables you to compile native applications based on HTML/Javascript, with some APIs to access device functions such as camera and accelerometer.

It supports Android, Symbian, Palm and Blackberry. It's a closed beta at the moment, but you can sign up for an invitation - apparently new users are invited weekly.

Comment: Actually , I am looking for an online complier ,emulator specifically for Adroid application development.

Answer (score 3):

For any kind of development you will need an SDK to develop / compile the programs.

Are you looking for a Demo collection? To run these, you might try : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/

Are you looking for a way to test an app on multiple platforms? Maybe have a look at this: http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/Services/android

Answer (score 2):

Not really, I don't think so. Even if there were such a location, you would not be able to use Android debugging tools, which are very handy for development.

You may want to look into [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.org/about) . It is probably as close to an install-free development environment as you get. Of course, it is also much more limited than native Android programs.

Comment: link dead now.. please check that

Answer (score 0):

No any compiler without Android studio can't compile android studio code

Comment: you might want to source your claim or add more details, a simple "no" can be seen as a low quality answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).